# How do browsers compare URLs for caching?

Tags: caching, browser, cross-browser, browser-cache, cache-control

Specifically, what portions of the URL are used for comparison.  Suppose I serve a CSS stylesheet at `https://www.example.com/a/b/test.css` with the appropriate HTTP headers for `cache-control`, `max-age`, etc.  When a user goes to each of the following URLs later, which of them will serve the cached file?

```
https://www.example.com/a/b/test.css
https://www.example.com/a/b/test.css?abc=123
https://www.example.com/a/b/test.css#abc=124
```

Basically, what I'm asking is whether or not the "search" and "hash" portion of the URL string are compared when the browser decides whether or not to use a cached resource.  Further, is this comparison logic consistent across browsers, or otherwise part of some standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RFC 7234 [states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-2):

> The primary cache key consists of the request method and target URI.

More fundamentally, RFC 7230 [explains that](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.1):

> The target URI excludes the reference's fragment component, if any,
> since fragment identifiers are reserved for client-side processing

Putting those two together, the first two resources are *not* equivalent (as the query is part of the URI). The last refers to the same resource as the first. This is standard-specified behaviour.

However, note that a previous version of the spec [stated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.2):

> Note: Section 13.9 of [RFC2616] prohibited caches from calculating
> heuristic freshness for URIs with query components (i.e., those
> containing '?').  In practice, this has not been widely
> implemented.

which suggests that some implementations wouldn't cache the second example unless specifically told that it was cacheable.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer!  Do you know which specific implementations ignore querystrings?  Specifically among modern browsers/webviews.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526887/733345) suggests "a lot of older browsers (including IE6)".